# How to append the json data from rest service in ajax call

Tags: javascript

When I am trying to append the data from rest services in ajax call.Only the last value is getting append to the table.

```
   function getReporteeList() {
$.ajax({
url:'http://localhost:8088/JirasTrackingApp/reporter/Reportees/ReporteeList/'+ $("#ManagerId").val(),
type:'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result){      

           var content = '';
           $.each(result,function(key,value){
               content += '<tr>';
               content = '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
               content = '<td>'+value.UserId+'</td>';
               content += '<td>'+value.count+'</td>';
               content += '</tr>';

           });
           $('#employee_table').append(content);


         }
   });
 }
```

The json data that is being returned in this format:

```
   0: {UserId: "at1234", count: 0, Name: "Amreen Taj"}
   1: {UserId: "AR1234", count: 0, Name: "Anagha R"}
   2: {UserId: "MS1234", count: 4, Name: "Madhusudan S"}
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
    Name    UserName    Count   
   MS1234    4
```

This is my html table:

```
       <table id = "employee_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: You keep using `=` and over-writing your `content` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lines

```
          content += '<tr>';
               content = '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
               content = '<td>'+value.UserId+'</td>';
               content += '<td>'+value.count+'</td>';
               content += '</tr>';
```

You sometimes have +=, sometimes have =;

It should explode but browser fixes invalid HTML structure automatically.

Comment: No problem. If you are new on StackOverflow then I recommend you to select the answer that solved your problem. It allows other users do not waste time for reading solved issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the += on two of the contents below:

```
content += '<tr>';
content = '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
content = '<td>'+value.UserId+'</td>';
content += '<td>'+value.count+'</td>';
content += '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this piece of code it should work

```
   var content = '';
       $.each(result,function(key,value){
           content += '<tr>';
           content += '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
           content += '<td>'+value.UserId+'</td>';
           content += '<td>'+value.count+'</td>';
           content += '</tr>';

       });
```